# Adding new osm.pbf files to the same osm tile server when using a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, docker-volume, docker-container

I'm using the instructions at switch2osm.org to create a docker container for the openstreetmap tileserver.  The instructions worked fine.  To summarize the instructions I followed (with a couple changes) at https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/:

1. Download PBF data
   wget https://download.geofabrik.de/africa/zambia-latest.osm.pbf
2. Create Docker volume:
   docker volume create openstreetmap-data
3. Import PBF data into volume:
   docker run -v /home/renderaccount/COUNTRY1-latest.osm.pbf:/data.osm.pbf -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main overv/openstreetmap-tile-server import
4. Run volume/container:
   docker run -p 8080:80 -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main -d overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:1.3.10 run

Like I said, this worked, but now I want to add another PBF file for a different region.  I'm not sure on the best way to do that.

Do I using the same Docker volume with the new PBF file, as in?

docker run -v /home/renderaccount/COUNTRY2-latest.osm.pbf:/data.osm.pbf -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main overv/openstreetmap-tile-server import

or do I have to using a different mount point for the new data, like

docker run -v /home/renderaccount/COUNTRY2-latest.osm.pbf:/data2.osm.pbf -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main overv/openstreetmap-tile-server import

or something else?